# Build a CentOS tile server

Tags: server, centos, protocols, openstreetmap, tiles

In order to build a CentOS 6.5 OSM tiles server I'm looking for some documentation and/or tutorials.

I tried [this one](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-14-04/) as I said in my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38871978/how-to-render-osm-tiles) but it worked on Ubuntu 14.04, not on CentOS 6.5...

Also, I want to be able to connect to my tiles from QGIS via the server URL.
It involves using some special protocols like WMS, WCS or WFS (I don't understand well about this).

If you have ideas you're welcome !

Comment: What about those directions doesn't work? What problem are you having exactly? What do `WMS`, `WCS` and `WFS` have to do with this question exactly?

Comment: I tried other solutions like [this one](http://osm2vectortiles.org/docs/getting-started/), the problem was about the rendered page, It's not possible to link it with QGIS. So I tried [this] (https://github.com/klokantech/tileserver-gl) but with this solution the server don't live "by itself" (docker dependant)... The fact about the protocols is that I don't really understand how it works exactly...

Comment: Please provide an exact description of your problem. Otherwise nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: I want to build a CentOS server that contains tiles and be able to use those tiles in QGIS in a distant computer

Comment: That's a plan and not a problem. What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: My ability to find documentation to make it work on a previous CentOS build, I don't have much experience in server configuration and it's a bit difficult to go alone.

Comment: I just realize that there's a Geographic Information Systems community, I'll go there to reach informations.

Answer (score 0):

You can try my gist to [build and run OSM tile server on CentOS 7](https://gist.github.com/coder4web/39e981adbc859db62576dc6840a4023b) with all up-to-date dependencies, work in progress and will be updated, but it works now.